# process and manage Tabular data stream in java programming

Tags: java

I want to know how to process and manage Tabular data stream in java programming.
consider there is a table of records has the scheme ( name, age, zip-code, disease) and the records are to be read and processed tuple by tuple in time as a stream. i want to manage these stream tuples to save the processed tuples with the the scheme ( age, zip- code, disease ) ( name attribute is supposed to be deleted )
for input example .. read Tuple 1 ( han, 25, 12548, flue)  at Time t1
publish Tuple 1* ( 25, 12548, flue)
read Tuple 2 ( alex, 27, 12544, cancer) 1 at t2 .
output Tuple 2* (27, 12544, cancer). 
  .. and so on, Can anyone Help me?

Comment: Your table of records is stored How? CSV text? Tab-delimited text?  Space-delimited text?  Relational database table?  Excel file? XML document?

Comment: It is expected to be stored as one of the following, Relational database table, Excel file and .Data File

Comment: Does "expected to be" mean _you_ get to choose from among those options?

Comment: No, Basically i don't the know format these will be stored with till now.
"expected to be" means it will be one of them but not sure if i can choose it myself.

Comment: There are techniques for handling each of these possibilities, but they're not interchangeable.  It would be better if you came back later with another question once you know what data format you'll be dealing it.  It you ant some research topics in the meantime, try JDBC for databases and Apache POI for Excel files.  For processing "ordinary"  files, the `java.io` package, `String` class, and `java.util.Scanner` class are handy and there are also various libraries out there in cyberspace for processing well-known file formats like CSV.  Best of luck :)

Comment: But, how i can simulate data stream generation and processing with these data ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions for a framework you can base your final application on.

First, make classes to represent your input  and output records.  We'll call them `InRecord` and `OutRecord` for the sake of discussion, but you can give them whatever names make sense for you.  Give them private fields to hold the necessary data and public getter/setter methods to access the data.

Second, define an interface for an input supplier; let's call it `InputSupplier` for this discussion.  It will need to provide methods for setup (`open()`) and tear-down (`close()`) methods to be called at the start and end of processing, and a `getNext()` method that returns the next available `InRecord`. You'll need to decide how it indicate end-of-input: either define that `getNext()` will return `null` if 
there are no more input records, or provide a `hasNext()` method to call which will return `true` or `false` to indicate if another input record is available.

Third, define an interface for an output consumer (`OutputConsumer`).  You'll want to have `open()` and `close()` methods, as well as an `accept(OutRecord)` method.

With this infrastructure in place, you can write your processing method:

```
public void process(InputSupplier in, OutputConsumer out){
    in.open();
    out.open();
    InRecord inrec;
    while ((inrec = in.getNext()) != null){
        OutRecord outrec = new OutRecord(in.getAge(), in.getZipCode(), in.getDisease());
        out.accept(outrec);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```

Finally, write some "dummy" I/O classes, one that implements `InputSupplier` and another that implements `OutputConsumer`.  For test purposes, your input supplier can just return a few hand-created records and your output consumer could just print on the console the output records you send it.

Then all you need is a `main` method to tie it all together:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    InputSupplier in = new TestInput();// our "dummy" input supplier class
    OuputConsumer out = new TestOutput(); // our "dummy" output consumer
    process(in, out);
}
```

For the "real" application you'd write a "real" input supplier class, **still implementing the `InputSupplier` interface**, that can read from from a database or an Excel file or whatever input source, and an new output consumer class, **still implementing the `OutputConsumer` interface**, that can take output records and store them into whatever appropriate format.  **Your processing logic won't have to change**, because you coded it in terms of `InputSupplier` and `OutputConsumer` interfaces.  Now just tweak `main` a bit and you've got your final app:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    InputSupplier in = new RealInput();// our "real" input supplier class
    OuputConsumer out = new RealOutput(); // our "real" output consumer
    process(in, out);
}
```

Comment: Great. but consider if it is required to edit the disease value of the input tuples so that i should be a list of values, each one belong to a different categorization level.For example : consider that disease values (Esophagus cancer, Lung cancer and Leukemia) belong to level 1 and (Stomach cancer and Lymphoma) belong to level 2. We want to read Tuple 1 (han,25,12548, Leukemia) in order to be published as (25,12548, "Stomach cancer,Leukemia") where "Stomach cancer,Leukemia" is the value of the disease attribute. Stomach cancer is randomly chosen form level 2 as Leukemia exits in level 1.